# Bootstrap-sass not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, rubygems

Bootstrap is not loading for me.  What am I doing wrong?

### application.scss (complete file, nothing else in it)

```
// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/theme";
```

### Gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass-extras'
```

### HTML IN HEADER SHOWS (running rails s, in development mode):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/stylesheets/application.css">
```

Comment: Try `bootstrap/scss/bootstrap`

Comment: Yes, does not work.

Comment: why have you included 3 different gems, just `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'` would work for you ?

Comment: Kept adding them when it was not loading.  I started with gem 'bootstrap-sass-extras', just removed bootstrap, but still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

have you try :

```
rails generate bootstrap:install static

rails generate bootstrap:install less
```

Comment: Yes, ran "rails generate bootstrap:install static" it again, but still does not work.

Comment: What is the path to the config.rb file?, I see a config.ru file

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hard to track down with the information you provided. Have you renamed your style files to .scss extention? Make sure you follow the installation instructions in the docs: [Bootstrap 4 alpha.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem)

It looks like you are using extra gems you don't need. If you are using the alph 4 version of bootstrap, you only need that in your gem file, you do not need version 3. Make sure include the right dependencies in your application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

as well as:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

in your application.scss file.

You have to configure these files and then make sure you restart your application in order for the changes to take place. Hope this helps!